# Reading matched line using File.ReadLines

Tags: c#, linq

I am searching for some string values in a large text file using File.ReadLines, On matching the criteria it returns true or false. All I want is to return the line (contents of the line, not the line number) when match found. Is there any way to achieve this with File.ReadLines, thanks?

```
isItThere = File
  .ReadLines(textBox2.Text).Any(x => x.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) ||
                                     x.Contains(date_to_chk1)));
```

I want the specific line when the match is found

Comment: Text of the line

Answer (score 2):

Note that there could be multiple matches, so i would use `Where`:

```
IEnumerable<string> matchingLines = File.ReadLines(textBox2.Text)
     .Where(line => line.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 
                 || line.IndexOf(date_to_chk1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 );
```

Note also that you should not use `String.ToLower` to compare strings in a case insensitive manner but `string.IndexOf` as shown above. Google [turkish `i`](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/) if you want to know why.

If you just want the first matching line you can still get it easily:

```
string firstMatchingLine = matchingLines.FirstOrDefault(); // null if no line matched
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lines that match your criterion, use `Where` instead of `Any`